# Trouble installing sendmail for app engine on mac

Tags: python, macos, google-app-engine, sendmail

Right now when I send mail the log says I'm "not currently sending out real email" and sure enough, when I send mail to myself I don't get anything.

I went into the docs and tried downloading sendmail from the linked site. I downloaded a file called sendmail.8.14.7.tar.gz.sig and ran the build file inside the extracted folder. I got

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
logout

[Process completed]
```

The READMEs were really confusing, and I'm not sure what to do in command-line to make this work. I tried

```
sudo ln -s /usr/sbin/sendmail /usr/bin/sendmail
```

and got "File exists". That's good, I guess. Then I tried

```
dev_appserver.py --enable_sendmail
```

and got "too few arguments"

What should I do to enable sendmail??

EDIT:
I then tried adding a boolean and my app's directory, this command resulted in a series of log updates that ended with

```
admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000...
```

But now when I run localhost, I get

```
google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.wsgi_server.BindError: Unable to bind localhost:8080
```

(8000 is the admin port of the app and 8080 is the port)

UPDATE:
Just read up the docs and realized that I don't need to set up sendmail or smtp for the deployed application, as "When your application is running on App Engine, it uses the App Engine mail service to send email messages." I tested it out and it worked!! So yeah. As of right now localhost sending mail doesn't really matter.

```
     ."".    ."",
     |  |   /  /
     |  |  /  /
     |  | /  /
     |  |/  ;-._ 
     }  ` _/  / ;
     |  /` ) /  /
     | /  /_/\_/\
     |/  /      |
     (  ' \ '-  |
      \    `.  /
       |      |
       |      |
```

Comment: You should add the apps name after the sendmail command: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Python_Using_Mail